# Accessing webpack variables from Nativescript 6.1 Core typescript file

Tags: nativescript

I have a NS 6.1 Core application.  In webpack I want to add a variable which I want to access later in a typescript file.  Here is my code:

```js
// Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                "process": "global.process",
                "myGlobal.environment": JSON.stringify(env.mode|| 'not defined'),
            }),
```

TS:

```js
declare let myGlobal: any;

export function onLoaded(e) {
    page = <Page>e.object;

    console.log('myGlobal.environment: ' + myGlobal.environment); 
}
```

The problem I am facing is that myGlobal is not defined when I run the code.

I tried deleting the platforms folder and rebuilding, but I get the same error.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `mode` in the `env` constant - use this to see what env actually is in this case `"myGlobal.MyScarySecret": JSON.stringify(env)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the env constant is **not** having a **mode** property but a boolean called **production**. Here is what env looks like

```
const {
    // The 'appPath' and 'appResourcesPath' values are fetched from
    // the nsconfig.json configuration file.
    appPath = "app",
    appResourcesPath = "app/App_Resources",

    // You can provide the following flags when running 'tns run android|ios'
    snapshot, // --env.snapshot
    production, // --env.production
    uglify, // --env.uglify
    report, // --env.report
    sourceMap, // --env.sourceMap
    hiddenSourceMap, // --env.hiddenSourceMap
    hmr, // --env.hmr,
    unitTesting, // --env.unitTesting,
    verbose, // --env.verbose
    snapshotInDocker, // --env.snapshotInDocker
    skipSnapshotTools, // --env.skipSnapshotTools
    compileSnapshot // --env.compileSnapshot
} = env;
```

As in JavaScript **undefined** equals **false** (for booleans), that means that if a **release** flag is not passed explicitly, the production will always be undefined (false). So you could do the following:

```
"myGlobal.environment": JSON.stringify(env.production || "development")
```

Or on second thought more like

```
"myGlobal.environment": JSON.stringify(env.production ? "production" : "development")
```